# List all terms from a vocabulary

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

I have a taxonomy called services and want to list out all the terms. I can load the vocab with

```
 $vocabulary = taxonomy_vocabulary_machine_name_load('Services')
```

but cannot seen to get all the terms out.

Comment: can you write detailed code?

Answer (score 49):

There are a few ways but I prefer [`entity_load()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/entity_load/7):

```
$vocabulary = taxonomy_vocabulary_machine_name_load('Services');
$terms = entity_load('taxonomy_term', FALSE, array('vid' => $vocabulary->vid));
```

You could also use:

- [`taxonomy_term_load_multiple()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_term_load_multiple/7)
- [`EntityFieldQuery`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21entity.inc/class/EntityFieldQuery/7)

Comment: Can you please explain the advantages of using `entity_load` ?

Comment: @NikhilM It's less characters to type than `taxonomy_term_load_multiple()` which is why I personally prefer it. Using `taxonomy_get_tree()` introduces unnecessary levels of complexity to the queries involved, unless you specifically need the terms in their original hierarchy (which OP didn't specify)

Comment: I like it, I think the answer below is a bit easier to read though.

Comment: @welovedesign Really? I prefer 2 lines over 6 but that's just personal preference :) As long as it's under 80 characters you're still adhering to Drupal's coding standards too

Comment: My +1 for the adhering to Drupal's coding standards

Answer (score 21):

I would like to use this code.

```
$name = 'YOUR_VOCAB_NAME';
$myvoc = taxonomy_vocabulary_machine_name_load($name);
$tree = taxonomy_get_tree($myvoc->vid);
foreach ($tree as $term) {
 echo $term->tid;
}
```

[taxonomy_vocabulary_machine_name_load](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_vocabulary_machine_name_load/7)

[taxonomy_get_tree](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_get_tree/7)

Comment: If you have a multilingual site, this does not work as desired. If I want all the terms, regardless of the language, this does not give you proper results. "taxonomy_get_tree" will parse results based on language. the above answer works for me