# Error on when to load node?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, 7

I have problem when our taxonomy term is linked with node but when i am clicking on term they go front page of site instead of current page
our code given below:

```
$ch1 = db_query("SELECT th.tid FROM taxonomy_term_hierarchy th 
  INNER JOIN taxonomy_term_data td ON th.tid=td.tid
  INNER JOIN field_data_field_books book ON book.field_books_tid = th.tid
  WHERE td.vid = '6' AND th.parent = $ch AND book.entity_id = $nid
 ")->FetchField();

$chap1=taxonomy_get_children($ch1);
foreach($chap1 as $ca1){
    $link = l($ca1->name, 'node/' . $ca1->nid)."<br>";
    print $link;
}
```

How to handle this problem?

Comment: Can you add more detail on your problem like where is your code? Moreover, Your query can be replaced by Drupal core function : [see this thread](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/64344/list-all-terms-from-a-vocabulary)

Comment: i am using this code in block but problem is that its only have tid values not nid

Answer (score 0):

"$ch1" contain tids.

The function "taxonomy_get_children($ch1);" retrieve all children term id and not related nid...

You can retrieve all nid linked with a term with this function [taxonomy_select_nodes](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_select_nodes/7)

I will suppose $ch1 contain your tids in an array

```
foreach($ch1 as $tid){
    $nids  = taxonomy_select_nodes($tid);
    $nodes = node_load_multiple($nids);
    foreach($nodes as $node){
        $link = l($node->title, 'node/' . $node->nid)."<br>";
        print $link;
    }
}
```

I can't test this code, if it's valid tell me and i will remove this line :)

Comment: please tell proper code i am new in drupal